# Two files into one line output of each in C program

Tags: c, file, while-loop, fgets

I am trying to make a main function that takes command line arguments that allow this program open two files (paths provided on the command line) and combines the two files one line at a time into one output. The first file provided are lines of text. Remove any trailing white space, tab, and new lines. The second files is a list of numbers, each of which you must add one to when printing to the output. Also, the two columns should be separated by a tab character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

const int MAXLEN = 4096;
const int MAXLINES = 10;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char buffer[MAXLEN];
  char buffer2[MAXLEN];
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  FILE *fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");

  if (!fp || !fp2) {
    perror ("Not Found");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int n = 0;
  while((n < MAXLINES) && (fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), fp)) && (fgets(buffer2, sizeof (buffer2), fp2))) {
    printf("%s\t%s", buffer, buffer2);
    n++;    
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
  fclose(fp2);

  return 0;
}
```

For example for input and output:

```
./c2 test/c2-testa test/c2-testb

  Test A  11
  Test B  51
  Test C  91
  Test D  26
  Test E  17
  Test F  76
```

This is what I received after `gcc` command:

```
c2:
c2.c:53:7: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
       fclose(fp);
       ^~~~~~
c2.c:53:7: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘fclose’ [-Wimplicit-int]
c2.c:53:7: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
c2.c:54:7: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
       fclose(fc2);
       ^~~~~~
c2.c:54:7: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘fclose’ [-Wimplicit-int]
c2.c:54:7: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
c2.c:56:7: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘return’
       return 0;
       ^~~~~~
c2.c:58:7: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
       }
       ^
make: *** [Makefile:31: c2.o] Error 1
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is when I compile this program is not do anything in gcc on Terminal.

Comment: A successful compilation produces a binary. Try executing the binary. Have a look at: http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/18.html

Comment: If you use command line arguments, always check if they are available. Checking for error on opening the files should look like `if(!fp || !fp2)` or `if(!(fp && fp2))`: You don't want to process if *any* of both did not open.

Comment: @Aconcagua, I really like `if(!(fp && fp2))` because I have never thought about it before... Thanks!

Comment: `int FILE * fp`: `FILE` *is* a data type already, so you do something comparable to `int int fp*`...

Comment: @Aconcagua, from my understanding, do you mean from `int FILE * fp` to `int int fp*`?

Comment: @DevinMorlan No, I came up with `int int*` only to better illustrate what's wrong... You instead need: `FILE* fp = ...` without the prepended 'int'.

Comment: Makes sense now... I updated the new compile message? Why do I still receive the same one as before?

Comment: @DevinMorlan Have a close look: when you edited the nested while loop to a single one, you left one surplus closing brace - so the calls to fclose now are outside a function context, and they are interpreted as function declarations (having no return type and fp being interpreded as type). Additionally, error message shows `fc2`, so in your actual code, there likely yet is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

What you did was print all lines from 2nd file for each line of the first file (nested loop). Your loop should look like that:

```
  int n = 0;
  while((n < MAXLINES) && (fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), fp)) && (fgets(buffer2, sizeof (buffer2), fp2))) {
    printf("%s\t%s", buffer, buffer2);
    n++;    
  }
```

Note that this does not take care of the "remove trailing white spaces". You might have to do some extra processing for that.

Also, your condition after opening the files should be `if(!fp || !fp2)` to make sure both files can be opened!!

Comment: I also updated it in the code so you may view the error compile.

Comment: @DevinMorlan In general, you shouldn't (significantly) change the code inside the question. It easily renders already given answers obsolete or even false, although they have been totally valid at the time being posted. If it has yet been acceptable in given case (only one single answer, changes denoted in comments, change secondary to actual problem) I won't try to judge, though... Just keep in mind for the future.